# Pass a full url with GET parameters via GET

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a intermediary page, i.e user clicks on a link that leaves the site a page tells you that you're now leaving the site.

An example link would look like this:

```
http://example.com/transitionpage.php?r=http://www.google.com
```

transitionpage.php then works with a simple

```
$redirectto = $_GET['r'];
header( "refresh:2;url=".$redirectto );
```

However I'm running into the problem that if the url you're redirecting to also has multiple GET parameters in it, the domain gets cut off at the first occurrence of `&`

So if the link was originally:

`http://example.com/transitionpage.php?r=http://www.google.com?par=1&par=2`

It would become:

`http://example.com/transitionpage.php?r=http://www.google.com?par=1`

Which is unfavorable.

How do I pass on the full URL via GET without it getting chopped off ? Do I have to escape it ?

Comment: Url encodings! See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp and http://ch1.php.net/urlencode

Comment: a simple  urlencode(); indeed did the trick, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do URL encoding: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
Your get query would translate to: http://example.com/transitionpage.php?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fpar%3D1%26par%3D2

These are the PHP methods you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: this gives me the expected result if I `echo $redirectto;` however in the actual redirect it does this `book?lang=en&amp;currency=THB&amp;` and the actual url doesn't work again ?

Comment: Yes! the value of the variable also comes out correct when printing, only when using it for the redirect it replaces the %26amp with &amp !?

Comment: It didn't work with `php header()` but works fine with meta refresh, strange!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$link = 'http://example.com/transitionpage.php?r='. urlencode('http://www.google.com?par=1&par=2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in function for Encoding Urls

for example

```
 urlencode("http://www.google.com");
```

for function refrence

[Urlencode Php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php%20http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)